# How to add success or error message on salesforce1?

Tags: apex, visualforce, developer

I created a VF page which is used for uploading files on Account object.
I was able to successfully upload the files on Mobile, but the problem is not able to give success or error message after uploading a file.

Can anyone please help me with this ? I am trying this on salesforce1

Visualforce :

```
 <apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="mobileAttachment">
<table>
<caption>
<h1><b> <p style="font-size:20px"> Attach File to Account {!Account.Name} </p></b></h1>
</caption>
<apex:form >
<tr>
<td>
<apex:inputfile value="{!myfile.body}" filename="{!myfile.Name}" />
<apex:commandbutton value="Save" action="{!Savedoc}"/>
</td>
</tr>
</apex:form>
</table>
</apex:page>
```

Controller :

```
public class mobileAttachment {

    public mobileAttachment(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {

    }
    Public Attachment myfile;
    Public Attachment getmyfile()
    {
        myfile = new Attachment();
        return myfile;
    }

    Public Pagereference Savedoc()
    {
        String accid = System.currentPagereference().getParameters().get('id');

        Attachment a = new Attachment(parentId = accid, name=myfile.name, body = myfile.body);

         /* insert the attachment */
         try {
         insert a;

          ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.INFO,'Attachment uploaded successfully'));
         }
         catch (DMLException e) {
          ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR,'Error uploading attachment'));
          return null;

         }


        return NULL;
    }   

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include

```
<apex:pageMessages />
```

in your VF-Page so that it knows where to show the message.